# gitlab slow when running on nginx subdomain

Tags: nginx, subdomain, gitlab

I'm trying to run gitlab on a subdomain.
I installed the latest gitlab version using the omnibus installer on my vserver (running Ubuntu 14.04.1) and disabled the bundled nginx and configured the unbundled nginx with the configuration posted here [How to setup a subdomain on nginx?](https://serverfault.com/questions/587991/how-to-setup-a-subdomain-on-nginx)

**/etc/nginx/sites-availible/gitlab**

```
upstream gitlab {
    server unix:/home/git/gitlab/tmp/sockets/gitlab.socket;
}

server {
listen 80 default_server;         # e.g., listen 192.168.1.1:80; In most cases *:80 is a good idea
server_name git.domain.com;     # e.g., server_name source.example.com;
server_tokens off;     # don't show the version number, a security best practice
root /home/git/gitlab/public;
client_max_body_size 500m;

# individual nginx logs for this gitlab vhost
access_log  /var/log/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
error_log   /var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

location / {
  # serve static files from defined root folder;.
  # @gitlab is a named location for the upstream fallback, see below
  try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab;
}

# if a file, which is not found in the root folder is requested,
# then the proxy pass the request to the upsteam (gitlab unicorn)
location @gitlab {
  proxy_read_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
  proxy_connect_timeout 300; # https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
  proxy_redirect     off;

  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
  proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;

  proxy_pass http://gitlab;
}
```

I'm able to visit the page, but it needs 30s and more to load the page. It is not taking so long when I'm using the bundled nginx server so I don't think it is a memory issue (and `free` is telling me that theres 1,4GB availible)

The error log tells me something like this:

**/var/log/nginx/gitlab_error.log**

```
server: git.mydomain.de, request: "GET /assets/application-c4186ca579dd09b3e48eaf1b5a3e4434.js HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket:/assets/application-c4186ca579dd09b3e48eaf1b5a3e4434.js"
```

Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm dealing with this exact same issue right now.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Upgrading to Gitlab 8.x fixed this issue for me

---

**Original Answer**:

I had this same issue and resolved it by directly copying the generated nginx config from the gitlab install to my nginx config directory.

I found my gitlab nginx config at: `/var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/gitlab-http.conf`

Pasting it here for posterity:

```
# This file is managed by gitlab-ctl. Manual changes will be
# erased! To change the contents below, edit /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
# and run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`.

## GitLab
## Contributors: randx, yin8086, sashkab, orkoden, axilleas, bbodenmiller
##
## Modified from https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/lib/support/nginx/gitlab-ssl & https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/lib/support/nginx/gitlab
##
## Lines starting with two hashes (##) are comments with information.
## Lines starting with one hash (#) are configuration parameters that can be uncommented.
##
##################################
##        CHUNKED TRANSFER      ##
##################################
##
## It is a known issue that Git-over-HTTP requires chunked transfer encoding [0]
## which is not supported by Nginx < 1.3.9 [1]. As a result, pushing a large object
## with Git (i.e. a single large file) can lead to a 411 error. In theory you can get
## around this by tweaking this configuration file and either:
## - installing an old version of Nginx with the chunkin module [2] compiled in, or
## - using a newer version of Nginx.
##
## At the time of writing we do not know if either of these theoretical solutions works.
## As a workaround users can use Git over SSH to push large files.
##
## [0] https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/Documentation/technical/http-protocol.txt#n99
## [1] https://github.com/agentzh/chunkin-nginx-module#status
## [2] https://github.com/agentzh/chunkin-nginx-module
##
###################################
##         configuration         ##
###################################

upstream gitlab {
  server unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/sockets/gitlab.socket fail_timeout=0;
}


server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name git.mydomain.com;
  server_tokens off; ## Don't show the nginx version number, a security best practice
  root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;

  ## Increase this if you want to upload large attachments
  ## Or if you want to accept large git objects over http
  client_max_body_size 250m;


  ## Individual nginx logs for this GitLab vhost
  access_log  /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/gitlab/nginx/gitlab_error.log;

  location / {
    ## Serve static files from defined root folder.
    ## @gitlab is a named location for the upstream fallback, see below.
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @gitlab;
  }

  location /uploads/ {
    ## If you use HTTPS make sure you disable gzip compression
    ## to be safe against BREACH attack.
    gzip off;

    ## https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    ## Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
    proxy_read_timeout      300;
    proxy_connect_timeout   300;
    proxy_redirect          off;

    proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Ssl     on;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
    proxy_set_header    X-Frame-Options     SAMEORIGIN;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab;
  }

  ## If a file, which is not found in the root folder is requested,
  ## then the proxy passes the request to the upsteam (gitlab unicorn).
  location @gitlab {
    ## If you use HTTPS make sure you disable gzip compression
    ## to be safe against BREACH attack.


    ## https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/694
    ## Some requests take more than 30 seconds.
    proxy_read_timeout      300;
    proxy_connect_timeout   300;
    proxy_redirect          off;

    proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
    proxy_set_header    X-Frame-Options     SAMEORIGIN;

    proxy_pass http://gitlab;
  }

  ## Enable gzip compression as per rails guide:
  ## http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#gzip-compression
  ## WARNING: If you are using relative urls remove the block below
  ## See config/application.rb under "Relative url support" for the list of
  ## other files that need to be changed for relative url support
  location ~ ^/(assets)/ {
    root /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public;
    gzip_static on; # to serve pre-gzipped version
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }


  error_page 502 /502.html;


}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually explain what is the part in the config that does the difference. It's also against the config files own commments: **Manual changes will be erased!** You should specify which option in your opinion affected the performance and reduce your post to that.

Comment: Yeah, I know this is a lazy answer. I didn't have the time to figure out what the problem was at the time and tabled it for later. Figured this piece of information will help some future person debug the problem better. Upgrading to the newest version of Gitlab resolved this for me permanently (so far).